# Round to 5 (or other number) in Python

Tags: python, rounding

Is there a built-in function that can round like the following?

```
10 -> 10
12 -> 10
13 -> 15
14 -> 15
16 -> 15
18 -> 20
```

Answer (score 476, accepted):

I don't know of a standard function in Python, but this works for me:

#### Python 3

```
def myround(x, base=5):
    return base * round(x/base)
```

It is easy to see why the above works.  You want to make sure that your number divided by 5 is an integer, correctly rounded.  So, we first do exactly that (`round(x/5)`), and then since we divided by 5, we multiply by 5 as well.

I made the function more generic by giving it a `base` parameter, defaulting to 5.

#### Python 2

In Python 2, `float(x)` would be needed to ensure that `/` does floating-point division, and a final conversion to `int` is needed because `round()` returns a floating-point value in Python 2.

```
def myround(x, base=5):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))
```

Comment: If only integers and rounding down, then you can also just do `x // base * base`

Comment: this is me being paranoid but I prefer to use `floor()` and `ceil()` rather than casting: `base * floor(x/base)`

Comment: @user666412 `math.floor` and `math.ceil` don't allow use with a custom base, so the preference is irrelevant.

Comment: this works great and rounds to an integer. If you want to round to floats, just remove the 'int' from the function. I wanted to round to values multiple of 0.05, and worked perfectly.

Comment: In case others stumble upon this, the suggested Python 3 way produces false results. `m = 2312**9; n = 3; m * round(n / m) == 1887515243828655024291056713728` where as using the Python 2 way in Py3, casting `x` or `base` as a float you get `m = 2312**9; n = 3; m * round(float(n) / m) == 1887515243828654813184824180736`

Comment: @bnlucas wow, thank you!  It seems like in Python 3, `/` converts both operands to `float` and loses precision. Even in Python 2, due to the size of numbers involved, the result isn't actually correct.  For example, using `float()` explicitly in Python 3: `m - m * round(float(n) / m)` gives a large residual instead of <= 3.

Comment: @bnlucas for large numbers, I'd recommend using `divmod()` and manually doing this. E.g., `m = 2312**9; n = 3; q, r = divmod(m, n); if r > n // 2: q+= 1; q *= n;` or something like that.

Answer (score 82):

For rounding to non-integer values, such as 0.05:

```
def myround(x, prec=2, base=.05):
  return round(base * round(float(x)/base),prec)
```

I found this useful since I could just do a search and replace in my code to change "round(" to "myround(", without having to change the parameter values.

Comment: You can use:
`def my_round(x, prec=2, base=0.05):
    return (base * (np.array(x) / base).round()).round(prec)` 
which accepts numpy arrays as well.

Comment: print(myround(10.205)) generate 10.24
print(myround(10.135)) generate 10.16

Comment: float typecasting no loger req if using >=py3.5 . find more detailed description at PEP 238: Changing the Division Operator.

Answer (score 26):

It's just a matter of scaling

```
>>> a=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>> for b in a:
...     int(round(b/5.0)*5.0)
... 
10
10
10
15
15
15
15
15
20
20
20
```

Answer (score 19):

Removing the 'rest' would work:

```
rounded = int(val) - int(val) % 5
```

If the value is aready an integer:

```
rounded = val - val % 5
```

As a function:

```
def roundint(value, base=5):
    return int(value) - int(value) % int(base)
```

Comment: I like this answer for rounding to the nearest fractional value.  i.e. If i only want increments of 0.25.

Answer (score 17):

```
def round_to_next5(n):
    return n + (5 - n) % 5
```

Answer (score 12):

```py
def round_up_to_base(x, base=10):
    return x + (base - x) % base

def round_down_to_base(x, base=10):
    return x - (x % base)
```

which gives

for `base=5`:

```py
>>> [i for i in range(20)]
[0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

```py
>>> [round_down_to_base(x=i, base=5) for i in range(20)]
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]

>>> [round_up_to_base(x=i, base=5) for i in range(20)]
[0, 5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

for `base=10`:

```py
>>> [i for i in range(20)]
[0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

```py
>>> [round_down_to_base(x=i, base=10) for i in range(20)]
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]

>>> [round_up_to_base(x=i, base=10) for i in range(20)]
[0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

tested in Python 3.7.9

Answer (score 10):

round(x[, n]): values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus n. So if n is negative...

```
def round5(x):
    return int(round(x*2, -1)) / 2
```

Since 10 = 5 * 2, you can use integer division and multiplication with 2, rather than float division and multiplication with 5.0. Not that that matters much, unless you like bit shifting

```
def round5(x):
    return int(round(x << 1, -1)) >> 1
```

Comment: +1 for showing us that round() can handle rounding to multiples other than 1.0, including higher values.  (Note, however, that the bit-shifting approach won't work with floats, not to mention it's much less readable to most programmers.)

Comment: @Peter Hansen thanks for the +1. Need to have an int(x) for the bit shifting to work with floats. Agreed not the most readable and I wouldn't use it myself, but I did like the "purity" of it only involving 1's and not 2's or 5's.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, I wanted to comment on Alok Singhai's answer, but it won't let me due to a lack of reputation =/

Anyway, we can generalize one more step and go:

```
def myround(x, base=5):
    return base * round(float(x) / base)
```

This allows us to use non-integer bases, like `.25` or any other fractional base.

Comment: This works as an answer in itself, though. I used it, without defining it as a function: y = base * round(float(x) / base). It works as long as you have already defined x and base. Note that this answer got seven upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
>>> def round_to_nearest(n, m):
        r = n % m
        return n + m - r if r + r >= m else n - r
```

It does not use multiplication and will not convert from/to floats.

Rounding to the nearest multiple of 10:

```
>>> for n in range(-21, 30, 3): print('{:3d}  =>  {:3d}'.format(n, round_to_nearest(n, 10)))
-21  =>  -20
-18  =>  -20
-15  =>  -10
-12  =>  -10
 -9  =>  -10
 -6  =>  -10
 -3  =>    0
  0  =>    0
  3  =>    0
  6  =>   10
  9  =>   10
 12  =>   10
 15  =>   20
 18  =>   20
 21  =>   20
 24  =>   20
 27  =>   30
```

As you can see, it works for both negative and positive numbers. Ties (e.g. -15 and 15) will always be rounded upwards.

A similar example that rounds to the nearest multiple of 5, demonstrating that it also behaves as expected for a different "base":

```
>>> for n in range(-21, 30, 3): print('{:3d}  =>  {:3d}'.format(n, round_to_nearest(n, 5)))
-21  =>  -20
-18  =>  -20
-15  =>  -15
-12  =>  -10
 -9  =>  -10
 -6  =>   -5
 -3  =>   -5
  0  =>    0
  3  =>    5
  6  =>    5
  9  =>   10
 12  =>   10
 15  =>   15
 18  =>   20
 21  =>   20
 24  =>   25
 27  =>   25
```

Answer (score 4):

Modified version of divround :-)

```
def divround(value, step, barrage):
    result, rest = divmod(value, step)
    return result*step if rest < barrage else (result+1)*step
```

Comment: so in this case you use divround(value, 5, 3)? or maybe divround(value, 5, 2.5)?

Comment: divround(value, 5, 3), exactly.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs "financial rounding" (0.5 rounds always up):

```
from decimal import ROUND_HALF_UP, Decimal, localcontext

def myround(x, base: int = 5):
    # starting with Python 3.11:
    # with localcontext(rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP):
    with localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP
        return base * int(decimal.Decimal(x / base).quantize(Decimal('0')))
```

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes) the rounding options are:

- `ROUND_CEILING` (towards *Infinity*)
- `ROUND_DOWN` (towards zero)
- `ROUND_FLOOR` (towards *-Infinity*)
- `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` (to nearest with ties going towards zero)
- `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` (to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer)
- `ROUND_HALF_UP` (to nearest with ties going away from zero)
- `ROUND_UP` (away from zero)
- `ROUND_05UP` (away from zero if last digit after rounding towards zero would have been 0 or 5; otherwise towards zero)

By default Python uses `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` as it has some statistical advantages (the rounded results are not biased).

Comment: Instead of setting the decimal context permanently as a side effect when the function is called, you should probably set it explicitly beforehand or even better use a [local context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

For integers and with Python 3:

```
def divround_down(value, step):
    return value//step*step


def divround_up(value, step):
    return (value+step-1)//step*step
```

Producing:

```
>>> [divround_down(x,5) for x in range(20)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
>>> [divround_up(x,5) for x in range(20)]
[0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

Comment: Hi, what do you think of my algorithm? Which is like yours but looks simpler https://stackoverflow.com/a/65725123/4883320

Comment: Hi @KiriSakow -- your solution looks good to me. To be honest, I don't know why I posted an answer for that question myself -- especially why I posted _that_ answer, which far from being excellent :/

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this (without explicit multiplication or division operators):

```
def rnd(x, b=5):
    return round(x + min(-(x % b), b - (x % b), key=abs))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Next multiple of 5**

Consider 51 needs to be converted to 55:

```
code here

mark = 51;
r = 100 - mark;
a = r%5;
new_mark = mark + a;
```

Answer (score 2):

No one actually wrote this yet I guess but you can do:

```
round(12, -1) --> 10
round(18, -1) --> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
 def divround(value, step):
     return divmod(value, step)[0] * step
```

Comment: Docs on divmod: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod

Answer (score 1):

I needed to round down to the preceding 5.

Example 16 rounds down to 15 or 19 rounds down to 15

Here's the code used

```
    def myround(x,segment):
        preRound = x / segment
        roundNum = int(preRound)
        segVal = segment * roundNum
        return segVal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C code. If I understand it correctly, it should supposed to be something like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int number;

printf("Enter number: \n");
scanf("%d" , &number);

if(number%5 == 0)
    printf("It is multiple of 5\n");
else{
    while(number%5 != 0)
        number++;
  printf("%d\n",number);
  }
}
```

and this also rounds to nearest multiple of 5 instead of just rounding up;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int number;

printf("Enter number: \n");
scanf("%d" , &number);

if(number%5 == 0)
    printf("It is multiple of 5\n");
else{
    while(number%5 != 0)
        if (number%5 < 3)
            number--;
        else
        number++;
  printf("nearest multiple of 5 is: %d\n",number);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to accepted answer, to specify rounding up or down to nearest 5-or-whatever

```
import math

def my_round(x, base, down = True):
    return base * math.floor(x/base) + (not down) * base
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works only with `int`s (it accepts `float`s, but the rounding behaves as if the decimal component doesn't exist), but unlike any solution relying on temporary conversion to `float` (all the `math.floor`/`math.ceil`-based solutions, all the solutions using `/`, most solutions using `round`), it works for arbitrarily huge `int` inputs, never losing precision, never raising exceptions or resulting in infinity values.

It's an adaptation of [the simplest solution for rounding *down* to the next lower multiple of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13082705/364696):

```
def round_to_nearest(num, base=5):
    num += base // 2
    return num - (num % base)
```

The round down recipe it's based on is just:

```
def round_down(num, base=5):
    return num - (num % base)
```

the only change is that you add half the base to the number ahead of time so it rounds to nearest. With exact midpoint values, only possible with even `base`s, rounding up, so `round_to_nearest(3, 6)` will round to `6` rather than `0`, while `round_to_nearest(-3, 6)` will round to `0` rather than `-6`. If you prefer midpoint values round down, you can change the first line to `num += (base - 1) // 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import isclose

def myPrice (p1,p2):
    return isclose(p1, p2, rel_tol=0.05)

print(myPrice(50.10,50.20))
```

To set a tolerance of 5%, pass rel_tol=0.05. The default tolerance is 1e-09

Answer (score -1):

I find this one to be negligibly slower than the answer by @mkrieger1 and @Alok Singhal but it is more explicit about the rounding behavior and easier to modify or extend.

```
def round_up_to_5(num):
    rounded_num = math.ceil(num / 5) * 5
    return int(rounded_num)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can “trick” `int()` into rounding off instead of rounding down by adding `0.5` to the 
number you pass to `int()`.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question