# Rounding down integers to nearest multiple

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python that allows me to round down to the nearest multiple of an integer?

```
round_down(19,10)=10
round_down(19,5)=15
round_down(10,10)=10
```

I conscientiously looked at SO and found nothing related to rounding ***down*** to a nearest base. Please keep this in mind before you post links to related questions or flag as duplicate.

Comment: If you found something to round up, why not using that and subtract one if the result and the original value are unequal?

Comment: I could have done it a million ways. I wanted a Python function to avoid littering my code with definitions, but I guess nothing to do this is included in Python and now I know. IG's answer looks pretty good though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to 5 (or other number) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5-or-other-number-in-python)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: That's a bad duplicate; there are much cleaner/fully-correct solutions for rounding *down* than for rounding to nearest, so adapting answers to that question to this question would lead to suboptimal solutions.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
def round_down(num, divisor):
    return num - (num%divisor)

In [2]: round_down(19,10)
Out[2]: 10

In [3]: round_down(19,5)
Out[3]: 15

In [4]: round_down(10,10)
Out[4]: 10
```

Answer (score 5):

This probably isn't the most efficient solution, but

```
def round_down(m, n):
    return m // n * n
```

is pretty simple.

Comment: And unlike using `floor(m / n)`, `m // n` never loses precision and works no matter how big the inputs are (the temporary `float` involved in `m / n` has precision and magnitude limits that `int`s lack).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following when in the same situation, making use of the `floor` function. In my case I was trying to round numbers down to nearest 1000.

```
from math import floor


def round_down(num, divisor):
    return floor(num / divisor) * divisor
```

Could do a similar thing with `ceil` if you wanted to define a corresponding always-round-up function as well(?)

Comment: This works, but involves way more, and more complex operation + import ... then the axepted ansler

Comment: Using ``float`` operations is limited by floating point resolution. For example, this will give wrong results for ``round_down(10000000000000000002001, 1000)``.