# How to define a number interval and then round up

Tags: python

I started trying：

```
(date.minute + 1) % 5
```

Later, I discovered that date.minute is not necessarily continuous. After 03 minutes, it is not necessarily 04 minutes. It may jump directly to 06 minutes.

So I need to be evenly divisible by 5 as the interval, and then count upwards.

For example, if the interval is 5, replace 6 with 5, 9 with 5, 10 with 10, and 14 with 10.

Comment: please be more specific about the result you are expecting. why  6 should be replaced by 5 but 14 replaced by 10 and not 15???

Comment: So, you want to round to the nearest 5?  That's `date.minute // 5 * 5`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082698/rounding-down-integers-to-nearest-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing floor division i.e., `// 5`:

```
>>> testcases = [6, 9, 10, 14]
>>> for tc in testcases:
...     print(f'{tc} -> {tc // 5 * 5}')
... 
6 -> 5
9 -> 5
10 -> 10
14 -> 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
    
x = math.floor(date.minute * 0.2) * 5
```

or equally use integer division `(date.minute // 5) * 5`