# Dynamically adding forms and handling the results

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

This is kind of a follow-up to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942096/change-query-parameter-via-select):

I'd like to be able to have users be able to click a 'more' button that, via jQuery, creates a new form (a duplicate of the first), allowing users to enter multiple search terms. I'm also planning on including some sort of `boolean` select box.

The result would be that users could search for stuff with "egg" in the name field of the database `AND` "1920" in the year field `OR` "San Francisco" in the location field, or "Le Bernadin" in the restaurant field `AND` "chicken" in the main ingredient field, or just "appetizer" in the course field (and no other parameters). I'm not particularly concerned about giving users terribly fine-grained control over the handling of the `boolean's`. I think just handling it linearly would be best e.g.

```
"a AND b OR c" --> (a AND b) OR c
"a OR b AND c" --> (a OR b) AND c
```

I've poked around on the internet, and I've found [this](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/), which seems like a good way to go about concatenating everything on the back-end, but I'm still confused about how to get to the point where I can start putting it all together. My current line of thinking involves using jQuery to dynamically add a `{{ form }}` template tag when the 'more' button is clicked, and then pulling apart `request.GET.lists()`. Is this the right way to go, or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/), which is very useful and ideal for be applied in your situation. Follow this link and you'll see what is and how can be used.

For adding/removing new forms dynamically [jquery.formset](http://django-dynamic-formset.googlecode.com/) is an excellent choice.