# Find closer number of a value considering given intervals - Python

Tags: python, math

I have to build a kind of an histogram, with given bins (I don't know if this is the best name to call them).
To exemplify:

The bins are:

-0.15|-0.10|-0.05|0.0|0.05|0.10|0.15

As input, I have a matrix which its values are between -0.16, 0.16, e.g.
So, if I read a 0.0884, I have to count it as 0.10. 
I know that, to do this, I could verify in what range this value fits, i.e, [0.05, 0.10]. The I could calculate the difference between the value and its upper bound and lower bound (each value in absolute). So, the value would be counting as in the bin with the smallest difference. 
But I found so simple codes to do really complex things in Python that I'm know wondering if there is a simple way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: From previous questions it looks like you have `matplotlib` available, which means you must have `numpy`; do you have to write a routine yourself for pedagogical or homework purposes, or can you simply use `np.histogram`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def get_bin(n, step=0.05):
    return step * round(n / step)
```

Examples:

```
>>> get_bin(0.0884)
0.1
>>> get_bin(-0.027)                                                                                                   
-0.05
>>> get_bin(-0.023)                                                                                                   
-0.0
```

This method is described well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2272174/505154

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm doing right now. Great to know that this is a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @F.J, I don't know if you could help me, but I noted that doing this sometimes I got -0.0. Do you know why the signal and how could I prevent this? Thank you.

Comment: [This is why it happens](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), to avoid this type of issue you can multiply everything by 100 (or 20) and use integers for your bins or take a look at the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want a Histogram, so I assume you want to allocate points in an ordered list of bins.
So here goes:

```
bins = ((-0.15,[]), (-0.10,[]), (-0.05,[]), (0.00,[]), (0.05,[]), (0.10,[]), (0.15,[]))

def store(point):
    for bin in bins:
        if point < bin[0]:
            bin[1].append(point)
            return
    bins[len(bins)-1][1].append(point)

store(0.0884)

bins
```