# How to round up to 32 using the math module (Python 3,)

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, rounding

Is it possible to round upwords using the built-in math module? I know that you can use math.floor() to round down, but is there a way to round up? Currently, I use this to round:

```
def roundTo32(x, base=32):
    return int(base * round(float(x) / base))
```

but that doesn't always round up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round to 5(or other number) in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5or-other-number-in-python)

Comment: @blueberryfields: That post uses the exact method the OP is using, to round to the nearest multiple. That means `15` is rounded *down*, not up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah, right. misread the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2273059/173773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`math.ceil()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) to round float values up:

```
import math

def roundTo32(x, base=32):
    return int(base * math.ceil(float(x) / base))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> def roundTo32(x, base=32):
...     return int(base * math.ceil(float(x) / base))
... 
>>> roundTo32(15)
32
>>> roundTo32(33)
64
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only use integers, you can also do:

```
def roundTo32(x):
    return (x + 31) & ~31
```

the part `& ~31` is possible because 32 is a power of two.