# How can I add zeroes to the end of a PyTorch tensor based on a modulo operation?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor with size: `torch.Size([1, 305760])`

Since `305760` is not divisible by 400, I want to change the size to: `[1, 306000]` filling the remaining spaces with `0`. How can I do this with PyTorch?

Comment: Are you wanting to add zeroes or round up to the nearest thousands place?

Comment: Both - add enough zeroes so that the size is a multiple of `400`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = torch.randn(1,305760)
N = a.shape[1]
M = 400
b = torch.zeros([a.shape[0], (N // M + 1 ) * 400 - N])
a = torch.cat((a, b), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement a rounding function that lets you specify the base you want to round to. This should work:

```
def myround(x, base):
    return base * -(-x // base)

torch.Size([1, myround(305760,400)])
```

Basing this off the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5-or-other-number-in-python) but modified to force rounding up.