# Rounding a Whole no. to nearest number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

### Rounding a Whole no. to nearest number in python

*Hello! 

I am designing a project in python where I'm stuck at a point. I hope I'll get my solution.

Python : 3.7.9 on windows 10*

*i.e. for example:*

1. 0 --> 0
2. 1 --> 0
3. 2 --> 0
4. 3 --> 0
5. 4 --> 0
6. 5 --> 0
7. 6 --> 10
8. 7 --> 10
9. 8 --> 10
10. 9 --> 10
11. 10 --> 10
12. 715306 --> 715310
13. 715305 --> 715300
    similarly for all big no.s too
    Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `round()` function like this.

```
print(round(46,-1))
print(round(45,-1))
print(round(715306,-1))
```

```
50
40
715310
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment because I don't have sufficient reputation. But you can refere to this link here:

[Round to 5 (or other number) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5-or-other-number-in-python)

A slight tweak can lead you to the right way:

```
def myround(x, base=10):
    return base * round(x/base)
print(myround(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Round numerical values up and down in Python**

When we round values, we go from a numerical value with decimal places to a whole number. With this process we do lose some precision, but the rounded value is often much easier to read and interpret.

**Python has three ways to turn a floating-point value into a whole (integer) number:**

- The built-in round() function rounds values up and down.

  round(5.4598)
- The math.floor() function rounds down to the next full integer.

  import math

  math.floor(12.75)