# Round to nearest number between two numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

How do I round a fraction to the nearest **0.5** between **0.0** and **5.0**?

Let's say I've got 11/150, it should convert to 0.0. In addition, 75/150 should convert to 2.5

As for the code I've got this but I'm lost as to where to go from here

```
# number is 11, and max is 150

number = float(percent / max)
number = round(p/0.5)*0.5
```

However, it **needs to round between 0.0 and 5.0** rather than 0 and 1.

EDIT 1:

It's best to treat it as a percentage. For example, let's say the percent given is 5o% (50/100, for ease). This means the result should be 2.5

In the same respect, 51% would still be 2.5.

However, 60% (60/100) would be 3.0

Comment: @B__ Clarified in extra line, it basically needs to treat it like a percentage, with the cap being 5.0 and the minimum being 0.0

Comment: Per the existing "already has answers" link, for non int values see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666678/361842

Comment: @JohnLBevan That doesn't do it between two values.

Comment: Alternative solution since you seem interested in fractions: `from fractions import Fraction; def round_to_half(numerator, denominator): return Fraction(numerator, denominator).limit_denominator(2)`

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by 2, round, then divide by 2

if you want nearest quarter, multiply by 4, divide by 4, etc

Comment: NB: Other way round: divide then multiply.  Also this only works if the data type's int/long (i.e. a whole number).

Comment: It needs to be a float

Comment: @JohnLBevan How would your "divide then multiply" work?

Comment: @JohnLBevan And why do you think this only works for ints?