# Rounding float to a base gives too many decimals

Tags: python

I want to round a number to a given base. Take the following example, where I want to round to the nearest 0.01:

```
number = 12.123123123
base = 0.01
base * round(number/base)
```

I expect the result `12.12`, but I get `12.120000000000001`. Why is that? Do I need to process the output somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails, because of this:

```
>>> 1212 * 0.01
12.120000000000001
```

The solution is this:

```
>>> round(12.123123123, 2)
12.12
```

Or, if you **really** want to use `base`:

```
>>> number = 12.123123123
>>> base = 0.01
>>> decimals = -round(math.log10(base))
>>> round(number, decimals)
12.12
```

The explanation for the "error" is here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: This might have issues when the base is not an integer power of 10.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Absolutely. Rounding to base = 7.2351 will not produce what you expect, regardless of what you expect :) That is why it makes no sense to have `base` at all IMO.

Comment: From what I understand the point isn't to round to specific decimal places but rather multiples of the base. For example suppose base were 5, then you'd round 18 to 20, 16 to 15 and so on. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5-or-other-number-in-python

Comment: Yes, the original code does that, but it uses base `0.01`, so it is not clear what is intentional and what just a coincidence. Anyway, if that was the intention, I would say the code from the question is actually correct :) The floating point "error" is then to be expected and should not be considered an error.

Comment: That basically implies that OP actually needs to use some other representation of numbers that normal floats, Python's builtin `Decimal` seems quite suitable and it has a nice `quantize` method that suits this exact purpose. See one of the duplicates this question is closed against.

Answer (score 1):

Might be you want this!

```
number = 12.123123123
base = 0.01
round(number / base) / base**(-1)
```

We want to avoid floating point precision limitations! To get a success, instead of *multiply* our rounded `number` by `base`, which value is `base = 0.01`, we can try to *divide* it by `base**(-1)`, which is *divide by 100*! We can do that **only** **if** `base**(-1)` **is** **integer** value. That is why because of exponentiation and arithmetic rules:

> a * (b ** x) = a / (b ** (-x))

> x * (1 / y) = x / y

We have `base = 0.01` and this is the same as `base = 10**(-2)`
So we can change base to `base = 10**(-(-2))` and change our multiply operation to division.

Comment: This might not work when `base**(-1)` is not an integer, for example `base = 0.15`.